# upgrade yuicompressor batch file

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I'm using yuicompressor 2.4.7 beceause 2.4.8 is still buged ([see here](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/78)), so i've made a little script to find and mimify js file, but when i run the script multiple time it create file with bad extension.
For an example :

1. first run : bla.js => bla.min.js
2. second run : bla.js => bla.min.js
   but it also create bla.min.min.js
3. etc

   `for /r %I in (*.js) do (
       java -jar "C:\Mimifer\yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar" "%~I" -o "%~dpnI.min.js"
   )`

Should i change the way to find files or its possible to exclude certain extension files ?
I've used [this](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to make this script

Comment: Helps to read the documentation for the command you are trying to use.  This is at the top of the documentation for the `FOR` command. **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable. Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different from %I.**

Comment: Yeah i konw, the current script is the version i used in the command prompter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /r %%I in (*.js) do echo %%I|find /i ".min.js">nul&if errorlevel 1 (
```

Note that all references in your batch to the `metavariable` **I** should be `%%I`, not `%I`. `%I` is only applicable if the command is executed from the prompt.

This command `echo`es the filename found through a pipe `|` to `find` which looks for a string `/i` in any case ".min.js". The output of the `find` command is discarded by being redirected to `nul`. If `find` finds the string, `errorlevel` is set to 0, otherwise `1`.

The `&` separates cascaded commands

The old original but still-supported syntax `if errorlevel 1` means "if the errorlevel is 1 or greater" (ie, in this case, the string was not found)